# VideoView android shows black screen for a second when setting visibility to gone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

I built a recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager. The goal is to display these imageviews as thumbnails and on click play the respective video behind it.
Everything is working fine except the following scenario.

1) When i click on an image, the image disappears(Visibility gone) and the video(Visibility visible) plays from the link, Now when i click on another video, the previous video disappears(Visibility gone  <-- This causes a black screen for a moment at its position) and the previous image appears (Visibility visible) and now new image disappers, new video appears on its respective grid position and it plays.

So it's like instagram search but with videos.

Now when I dont do videoView.setVisibility(GONE), videoview stays behind the image which eventually makes scrolling lagging as no. of videos appear.

Can any one help me figure out the issue ? I first make the image's visibility visible and then videoview disappear.

Here's the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/cellLayout"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<VideoView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:visibility="gone"

    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Count"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: I also tried with another thread, but it's the same. 
There was a flickerduring the start as well when i made the imageview disappear and videoview appear. However i used animateLayoutChanges= true. So it handled the starting flicker however it didn't work at the end.

Comment: try using `TextureView` instead of `VideoView`

Comment: yes textureview is the best solution

Comment: Thank you. TextureView worked like a charm!

Comment: @Sagar can you please tell me how to use TextureView instead of VideoView ?

Comment: @Sagar Please post you code in answer section. Thanks

Comment: @TusharLathiya I dont' have this code anymore. Due to some Legal reasons I didn't upload the code base for this on my repository and Unfortunately, I don't have this code anymore. Sorry! But let me know if you are stuck at something. Would be happy to help.

Comment: @Sagar No Problem.. Thanks for reply.